# Is there a software for defining areas in Windows for sticking windows in them?

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, window-manager

There are some softwares offered by Philips or Asus that come with their Monitors.

Like when in Windows 7, if you pull a windows far to the left, it will suggest that the windows will take half of the space in the desktop.

But I want to divide my screen to 4 equal squares. So if I pull a windows to top left corner, it should automatically adjust to 25% of the total screen.

Hope what I am telling is clear,

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [Aquasnap](http://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap/28). It's free to download for personal use and it can only be used on a single monitor. You have to pay to unlock multi-monitor support.

Key features include:

> - Can resize windows to half screen and quarter screen.
> - Multi-monitor compatible (paid version).
> - Works with child windows of Multiple Document Interface (MDI).
> - Skinnable interface.
> - Multilingual GUI.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/hoppfrosch/WindowPadX

It's free, it works on multiple monitors.

You just have to watch the config because it "traps" the 0 on the numlock keyboard.

I use it daily!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is the following free tool, a desktop window manager with configurable short cuts, I've been using this myself for a good few years and never had any problems with it.

http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/

Answer (score -3):

This is for future:

I found something called: MaxTo. Really nice.

Comment: Please add/edit more information: Summary, screenshot, features and that it is not free

Comment: Who said it needed to be free?

Comment: No link, no description, just a name. Thats not the way software recommendations are done on SU: http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/50173

Comment: You did not answer my question. Who said it needs to be free?

Comment: Nobody said that it needs to be free. However, adding this kind of information kinda helps other folks reading through the posts.

Comment: How does writing " this is not free " help someone read a post?